# Mahan Second Quantisation Interaction Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, many-body

Mahan give the Hamiltonian as
$$H=\sum_{mn}H_{nm}b_n^\dagger b_m+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{klmn}V_{klmn}b_k^\dagger b_m^\dagger b_n b_l$$
$$V_{klmn}=\iint\phi_k^*(\textbf{r}_i)\phi_l(\textbf{r}_i)V(\textbf{r}_i-\textbf{r}_j)\phi_m^*(\textbf{r}_j)\phi_n(\textbf{r}_j)d^3r_id^3r_j$$
I think he has the indices for $\textbf{r}_i$ and $\phi$ wrong, my version is
$$V_{klmn}=\iint\phi_k^*(\textbf{r}_j)\phi_l^*(\textbf{r}_i)V(\textbf{r}_i-\textbf{r}_j)\phi_m(\textbf{r}_i)\phi_n(\textbf{r}_j)d^3r_id^3r_j$$
with two conjugates on the LHS, and the integration indices "bracketed".  This is for bosons, since I think there is a difference, but I cannot remember what it is exactly.  Is this really a typo or is Mahan correct?

Comment: Why not checking any other source? How did you arrive at your version? BTW: there is a typo in both versions, somewhere should be a $l$ index.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I've also checked Altland and Simons, but I have heard that one also has typos.  That being said, Altland and Simons looks closer to my solution (except he doesn't have the indices, so there could be a difference there as well.

Comment: Ok...but there are plenty of online sources available... I mean what do you expect us here to answer except giving a reference?

Comment: @TobiasFünke is there a reference which has the indices as well?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean with indices here. This is a fairly standard topic, and as I said there are dozens of sources: books, lecture notes etc. You should also make sure to understand that different books might use different conventions (e.g. the ordering/labeling of the indices of operators in combination with the matrix elements)...

Comment: Don't the $\phi$ states commute? Also, I'm not sure where you're looking in Altland & Simons. Ch. 2 in my copy might use $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r}'$ instead of subscripts, but those are clearly equivalent notations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is
$$V_{klmn}=\iint\phi_k^*(\textbf{r}_j)\phi_m^*(\textbf{r}_i)V(\textbf{r}_i-\textbf{r}_j)\phi_n(\textbf{r}_i)\phi_l(\textbf{r}_j)d^3r_id^3r_j$$
Since the matrix element of the transformation is given by the inner product, either both conjugates have to be on the LHS, representing the matrix operating on the vector, or all the conjugates are on the RHS, representing the adjoint of the transformation operating on the dual basis.  There should then be functions of $r_i$ and $r_j$ (exact order doesn't matter as long as they're on one side of the operator, the statistics come from the operators), to represent the inner product over each independent set of basis vectors for the vector space representing states of particles $i$ and $j$ (i.e. the integral corresponds to the continuum of $\varphi_k\otimes\varphi_m(v_n,v_l)$ where $\varphi_i$ form the dual basis for $v_i$).